# Can Oauth be used securely from the client side for a back-end service?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a web app (C# / Javascript) where I want to call a back-end service that I own. I want to secure that service so only my app(s) can call it. Seems like if I use Oauth on the client side, the secret is exposed? All the docs I read about Oauth give solutions when the user of the app owns the resource, not when the app itself owns it. I was looking at how google apis work, and the JavaScript libraries seem to expose the key on the client side, no?

Comment: Do you mean you want to restrict your API just for the JavaScript served with your frontend applications?

Comment: @JánHalaša For this particular case, yes. But I'd like to be able to restrict it to any of my apps, not just web apps, like C#, etc. Anything I control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can accomplish this with OAuth, but how you go about it depends on the details of how the data accessed via your back-end service is organized. If the data is actually user-specific, then your user really is the resource owner. In this case you would use the typical authorization code grant. With this grant type you register a client with the OAuth auth server and receive a client_id and client_secret. The client_id is, indeed, exposed in the browser, but the client_secret sits in your web app server and is never exposed. It is only sent on back-channel (non-browser) requests to your auth server. The main thing here is that only your own client web app would be registered and receive the client_id/client_secret. You simply need to not provide any public registration endpoints so no other clients can register. With this grant type, in order for your web app to gain authorization to access the user's data on the back-end service, the user would need to approve the authorization in the browser as part of the process.

On the other hand if the data you're accessing on your back-end service is not user-specific, then you can use the OAuth Client Credentials grant. With this grant type you register the client as before and receive a client_id and client_secret. The secret is stored securely on your web app server and only passed in back-channel requests. You would avoid allowing any other clients to register. Your web app can then gain authorization to your back-end service without even needing any user authorization in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to restrict your API to be called just by the code of your applications. Browser applications with public codes cannot hold any secret (such as certificate), that would identify them, because anyone can extract it from the code. Desktop and mobile applications compiled to bytecode are not so easy to read, but with some effort, attacker could find the secret data. That's also the reason why these applications (so called public clients) don't hold client_secret if they act as OAuth2 clients. They use a one-time secret instead - [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).

What you can do, is to check the audience (what client ID the token was issued for) of an access token sent from a frontend application to your backend. You can get this info either from the [token introspection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) (`aud` attribute) or from [JWT attributes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) if the token is of JWT type.